# Splitting a cookie string into a 2D array

Tags: php, c

I am writing possibly my first real C project, and it is almost finished. But as I was coming to a close I noticed something.

This is a simple operation to split a cookie string into a ~2D array. I don't expect you to read all of the code if you don't want to.  It works, but that is not my current worry.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <zlib.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct _http_cookie_t
{
    const char * key;
    const char * val;
    unsigned int key_len;
    unsigned int val_len;
} http_cookie_t;

int cookies_get_length(char * s);
int cookies_contains(http_cookie_t ** cookies, int length, const char * string);
int cookies_create_map(http_cookie_t ** cookies, int length, char * string);
int cookies_separate_string(char ** cookies, int length, char * string);
int cookies_create_single(http_cookie_t * cookie, char * src);

int main() {

    const char * src = "UREF1=F2E2D08C;UREF2=F2E2D08C";

    const int length = cookies_get_length((char *)src);
    http_cookie_t ** cookies = (http_cookie_t **)malloc(length * sizeof(struct http_cookie_t));
    cookies_create_map(cookies, length, (char *)src);

    if (cookies_contains(cookies, length, "UREF")) {
        printf("WAS FOUND");
    } else {
        printf("NOT FOUND");
    }

    return 0;
}

int cookies_contains(http_cookie_t ** cookies, int length, const char * string)
{
    int located = 0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        http_cookie_t * c = cookies[i];

        if (strcmp(string, c->key)) {
            located = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    return located;
}

int cookies_create_map(http_cookie_t ** cookies, int length, char * string)
{
    char * strings[length];
    cookies_separate_string(strings, length, string);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i<length; i++) {
        cookies[i] = (http_cookie_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct http_cookie_t));
        cookies_create_single(cookies[i], strings[i]);
    }

    return 1;
}

int cookies_separate_string(char ** strings, int length, char * src)
{
    const char semicolon[2] = ";";
    char *d = (char *)malloc(strlen(src) + 1);

    if (d == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(d, src);
    char * v = strtok(d, semicolon);

    int i = 0;

    while (v != NULL) {
        strings[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(v));
        strings[i] = v;

        i++;
        v = strtok(NULL, semicolon);
    }

    return 1;
}

int cookies_create_single(http_cookie_t * cookie, char * src)
{
    const char sign[2] = "=";
    char *d = (char *)malloc(strlen(src) + 1);

    if (d == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    strcpy(d, src);
    char * v = strtok(d, sign);

    char * strings[2];
    int i = 0;

    while (v != NULL) {
        if (i < 2) {
            strings[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(v));
            strings[i] = v;
        }

        v = strtok(NULL, sign);
        i++;
    }

    if (i < 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    cookie->key = strings[0];
    cookie->val = strings[1];

    cookie->key_len = (int)strlen(cookie->key);
    cookie->val_len = (int)strlen(cookie->val);

    return 1;
}

int cookies_get_length(char * s)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; s[i]; s[i]==';' ? i++ : *s++);

    return i + 1;
}
```

My concern is that I was able to create the exact same procedure in PHP which looks like this:

```
<?php

$src = 'UREF1=F2E2D08C;UREF2=F2E2D08C';
$cookies = array();

foreach (explode(';', $src) as $pair) {
    $pair = explode('=', $pair);

    $cookies[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}

echo '<pre>';

print_r($cookies);
```

Now I need some advice, taking into account this being my first C program and having likely made a few mistakes in optimization.

But please either explain why my C solution is massively larger, or explain how I can simplify it. You may ignore the PHP comparison context of this question.

=====================================================================

I modified the script since this question was originally posted.  I took a large amount of advise from other questions I asked and updated the program accordingly.

The updated version is:

- C only
- Frees memory
- Includes better use of typedef

It is essentially a refactor of the previous version and is built as the actual apache module.

```
#include "httpd.h"
#include "http_config.h"
#include "http_protocol.h"
#include "ap_config.h"

#include <ctype.h>
#include "openssl/rand.h"
#include "zlib.h"

const char * COOKIE_KEY = "FGID";

typedef struct
{
    const char * key;
    const char * val;
    unsigned int key_len;
    unsigned int val_len;
} http_cookie_t;

char * cookie_create(request_rec *r);

typedef struct {
    int total;
    int max;
} explode_count_t;

typedef struct {
    char ** elements;
    int len;
    int max;
} explode_t;

explode_count_t * explode_count(char * haystack, char * needle);
void remove_explode_count_t(explode_count_t * count);

explode_t * explode(char * delimiter, char * string);
void remove_explode_t(explode_t * explode);

char * str_dup(char * source);

char * trim (char *string, char junk);
char * ltrim(char *string, char junk);
char * rtrim(char* string, char junk);

char * create_unique_ref();

/* The sample content handler */
static int cookie_uref_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    const char * src = apr_table_get(r->headers_in, "Cookie");
    char * hash;

    if (src == NULL) {
        hash = cookie_create(r);
    } else {
        char * header = str_dup((char *)src);
        explode_t * pairs = explode(header, ";");

        int has_cookie = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i; i < pairs->len; i++) {

            char * element = trim(pairs->elements[i], ' ');
            explode_t * single_pair = explode(element, "=");


            if (single_pair->len == 2 && strcmp(single_pair->elements[0], COOKIE_KEY) == 0) {
                has_cookie = 1;

                hash = malloc(strlen(single_pair->elements[1]));
                strcpy(hash, single_pair->elements[1]);
            }

            remove_explode_t(single_pair);
        }

        remove_explode_t(pairs);

        if (! has_cookie) {
            hash = cookie_create(r);
        }

    }

    free(hash);

    return DECLINED;
}

static void cookie_uref_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
{
    ap_hook_handler(cookie_uref_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
}

/* Dispatch list for API hooks */
module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA cookie_uref_module = {
        STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
        NULL,                  /* create per-dir    config structures */
        NULL,                  /* merge  per-dir    config structures */
        NULL,                  /* create per-server config structures */
        NULL,                  /* merge  per-server config structures */
        NULL,                  /* table of config file commands       */
        cookie_uref_register_hooks  /* register hooks                      */
};

char * cookie_create(request_rec *r)
{
    char cookie_header[100];

    char * hash = create_unique_ref();
    sprintf(cookie_header, "%s=%s; Path=/; Max-Age=3600; Version=1", COOKIE_KEY, hash);

    apr_table_set(r->headers_out, "Set-Cookie", cookie_header);

    return hash;
}

char * str_dup(char * source)
{
    char * copy = malloc(strlen(source));
    strcpy(copy, source);

    return copy;
}

explode_count_t * explode_count(char * haystack, char * needle)
{
    explode_count_t * count = malloc(sizeof(explode_count_t));

    count->total = 1;
    count->max   = 0;

    int hay_length = (int)strlen(haystack);
    int ndl_length = (int)strlen(needle);

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int m = 0;

    for (i; i < hay_length; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle[j]) {
            if (j == ndl_length - 1) {
                count->total++;
                j = 0;

                if (m > count->max) {
                    count->max = m;
                }
                m = 0;
            } else {
                j++;
            }
        } else if(haystack[i] == needle[0]) {
            j = 1;
        } else {
            j = 0;
            m++;
            if (m > count->max) {
                count->max = m;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

void remove_explode_count_t(explode_count_t * count)
{
    free(count);
}

explode_t * explode(char * string, char * delimiter)
{
    explode_t * explode = malloc(sizeof(explode_t));

    explode_count_t * count = explode_count(string, delimiter);

    explode->elements = malloc(sizeof(char *) * count->total);
    explode->len   = count->total;
    explode->max   = count->max;

    if (explode->max > 0) {
        char * copy = malloc(strlen(string));
        strcpy(copy, string);

        int i = 0;
        char * v = strtok(copy, delimiter);

        while (v != NULL) {

            explode->elements[i] = malloc(strlen(v) + 1);
            strcpy(explode->elements[i], v);

            v = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            i++;
        }

        free(copy);
    } else {
        explode->elements[0] = "";
    }

    remove_explode_count_t(count);

    return explode;
}

void remove_explode_t(explode_t * explode)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i; i < explode->len; i++) {
        free(explode->elements[i]);
    }

    free(explode->elements);
    free(explode);
}

char* trim (char *string, char junk)
{
    return ltrim(rtrim(string, junk), junk);
}

char* ltrim(char *string, char junk)
{
    char* original = string;
    char *p = original;
    int trimmed = 0;
    do
    {
        if (*original != junk || trimmed)
        {
            trimmed = 1;
            *p++ = *original;
        }
    }
    while (*original++ != '\0');
    return string;
}

char* rtrim(char* string, char junk)
{
    char* original = string + strlen(string);
    while(*--original == junk);
    *(original + 1) = '\0';
    return string;
}

char * create_unique_ref()
{
    char * hash = malloc(sizeof(char) * 80);

    unsigned long crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
    unsigned int  length = 30;
    unsigned char buf[30] = "";

    RAND_bytes(buf, length);

    unsigned char *c = NULL;

    for (c = buf; *c != '\0'; c++) {
        crc = crc32(crc, buf, length);
    }

    sprintf(hash, "%x", (int)crc);

    char *p = NULL;
    for (p = hash; *p; *p = (char)toupper(*p), p++);

    return hash;
}
```

A side note is that this does crash on phpmyadmin, I have yet to discover why.

Comment: This is actually a C++ program, but it has some C-isms in it. Regardless, this is not a code review site. But I will throw you a bone: check out [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and [C++ 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) for newer libraries and features that might make your code much simpler.

Comment: @snowman this is a testing ground I'm using it happens to be a C++ project.  This code is being moved to a C Apache module.

Comment: You're wondering why an interpreted language which aims is to make life easier is... easier to write than a language which aims is to make everything fast and efficient? Your answer in right in your question.

Comment: @OlivierPons I added the note at the bottom of the question to clarify that I know that now.

Comment: @OlivierPons While what you say is true, please note that the OP isn't experienced in C. There might be other - less obvious - reasons for the size difference in the two snippets.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound cheeky, this is not what I want. `C` is far more efficient than any other language but assembly. And like all low-level languages you will always have more things to write to reach your goal, whatever goal it is.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I refactored to, I deleted the original question before it was migrated as it was no longer relevant, however as this is now on code review, I have added the proper fully functional apache module.  It is designed to add a permanent cookie.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things that may help your improve your code.

### Decide which language you're using

The code looks mostly like C, but won't compile as C because it has a few things that are C++.  I'm going to assume you're really intending to write C for this review.  If it were C++, I'd suggest a completely different approach.

### Remove things that aren't C

Remove `#include <iostream>` and `using namespace std` because they are not C.

### Use your `typedef`s

The code correctly and reasonably defines a `typedef` for `http_cookie_t` but then uses  lines like this:

```
cookies[i] = (http_cookie_t *)malloc(sizeof(struct http_cookie_t));
```

First, that won't (or shouldn't) compile because the struct actually has a leading underscore (`_http_cookie_t`), and second, you can use the `typedef` to simplify the code:

```
cookies[i] = (http_cookie_t *)malloc(sizeof(http_cookie_t));
```

### Use pointers rather than indexing

In C, it's usually more efficient to use pointers rather than indexing. Even if you don't care too much about the performance of the code, this also makes the code more idomatic C. You almost certainly don't want to use both except in very special circumstances. So in `cookies_get_length`, for instance, the code is currently this:

```
int cookies_get_length(char * s)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; s[i]; s[i]==';' ? i++ : *s++);

    return i + 1;
}
```

This is broken code because of the last part of the `for` clause.  The expression  `s[i]==';' ? i++ : *s++` says that if `s[i]` is a semicolon, increment `i`, otherwise increment `s*`.  If you feed this code this string `";"` it will never terminate. If you feed it a `NULL` pointer, it will crash.  Do you see why? A better way to write the loop would be this:

```
int cookies_get_count(const char * s)
{
    int cookie_count = 0;
    if (s == NULL)
        return cookie_count;
    for (++cookie_count; *s; ++s)
        if (*s == ';')
            ++cookie_count;
    return cookie_count;
}
```

Note that the code bails out early if it gets a `NULL` pointer, that the loop is much simpler and that the name is more descriptive -- it's really a *count* of cookies, rather than the length.  Also, the parameter is declared as `const char *s`.

### Don't cast result of `malloc`

The `malloc` call returns a `void *` and one of the special aspects of C is that such a type does not need to be cast to be converted into another pointer type. So for example, this line:

```
http_cookie_t ** cookies = (http_cookie_t **)malloc(length * sizeof(http_cookie_t));
```

could be shortened to this:

```
http_cookie_t ** cookies = malloc(length * sizeof(http_cookie_t));
```

However, you *should* check the return value to assure it isn't `NULL` because that is an indication that the program has run out of memory and is a serious error.

### Eliminate unused variables

In the `cookies_separate_string` routine, the parameter `length` is never used and can be eliminated.

### Use `const` where practical

In all of your functions, the last parameter is a pointer to a string.  In all cases, that string is unmodified by the function and so can (and should) be declared as `const char *`.

### Consider a more efficient algorithm

Right now, the code makes many passes through the same string, but it's quite possible to do everything in a single pass.  Such an algorithm would likely shorten the code considerably.

### Don't leak memory

This code calls `malloc` several places but never `free`.  This means that the routines are leaking memory. It would be much better to get into the habit of using `free` for each call to `malloc` and then assuring that you don't leak memory.

Comment: Thanks for your review.  I have updated the question with the code after I refactored it a few weeks ago.  It is the actual code intended to be used so an updated review of this would be appreciated.